# Disabling user input for UITextfield in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, editing

pretty trivial question, I know. But I can not find anything online.

I need to disable the user from being able to edit the text inside of a text field. So that when the click on the text, a keyboard doesn't show up.

Any ideas?

A programmatic solution or if it is possible through storyboards would be great.

Comment: use a label instead?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Try this:

**Swift 2.0**:

```
textField.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

**Swift 3.0**:

```
textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Or in storyboard uncheck "User Interaction Enabled"

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had a look in the attributes inspector. Maybe I'm just not very observant -___-

Answer (score 63):

Another solution, declare your controller as UITextFieldDelegate, implement this call-back:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTextField.delegate = self
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == myTextField {
        return false; //do not show keyboard nor cursor
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Swift 4: func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)

Comment: I like this solution the best, and here's why: I might want to disable text entry in my field, but still receive touch events for the `leftView` or `rightView` of the field. An example of this: let's say I want the text field to act as a drop down. I don't want the user to be able to enter anything he or she wants, but I want to know if they click the "drop down" arrow in my text field's `rightView`. Sure there are other solutions to drop downs, but this seems clean and allows you to use the same styling as your other text fields without needing to create a whole different class / object.

Comment: better solution in my case...

Answer (score 35):

In storyboard you have two choise:

1. set the control's 'enable' to false.

[image]

2. set the view's 'user interaction enable' false

[image]

The diffierence between these choise is:

the appearance of UITextfild to display in the screen.

[image]

1. First is set the control's enable. You can see the backgroud color is 
   changed.
2. Second is set the view's 'User interaction enable'. The backgroud color is NOT changed.

Within code:

1. `textfield.enable = false`
2. `textfield.userInteractionEnabled = NO`

   **Updated for Swift 3**

   1. `textField.isEnabled = false`
   2. `textfield.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: I like how you provided the screenshot to show the difference between the two. 

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do it while keeping the user interaction on.
In my case I am using (or rather misusing) `isFocused`

```
self.myField.inputView = UIView()
```

This way it will focus but keyboard won't show up.

Comment: Exactly the behaviour I'm looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I like to do it like old times. You just use a custom UITextField Class like this one:

```
//
//  ReadOnlyTextField.swift
//  MediFormulas
//
//  Created by Oscar Rodriguez on 6/21/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Nica Code. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ReadOnlyTextField: UITextField {

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // Avoid keyboard to show up
        self.inputView = UIView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Avoid keyboard to show up
        self.inputView = UIView()
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        // Avoid cut and paste option show up
        if (action == #selector(self.cut(_:))) {
            return false
        } else if (action == #selector(self.paste(_:))) {
            return false
        }

        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In swift 5, I used following code to disable the textfield

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.textfield.isEnabled = false
   //e.g
   self.design.isEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2 / Xcode 10.1:**

Just uncheck behavior **Enabled** in your storyboard -> attributes inspector.

Comment: It appears to be Enabled rather than Editable. Was it changed?

Comment: You are right, It is Enabled. Typing mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use `UILabel` instead if you don't want the user to be able to modify anything in your `UITextField`

A programmatic solution would be to use `enabled` property:

```
yourTextField.enabled = false
```

A way to do it in a storyboard:

Uncheck the *Enabled* checkbox in the properties of your `UITextField`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false